# How to handle inline comments?

Tags: python, sql, parsing, antlr

I've used antlr based on Presto grammar to parse SQL queries. 
To define comments I've used:

```
SIMPLE_COMMENT
    : ('--'|'#') ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n'? -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

And this works ok when the comment is at the beginning of the line. But when the comment isn't in the beginning of the line it's not ignored.

for example when I have a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1--comment
```

I'm not ignoring the "---comment".

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: when I'm using space before the comment it's parsed ok. The thing is I have no control regarding the query structure and I wish to parse all queries...

Comment: Because of the ambiguity in the default comment character (what were they thinking in 1989?), inline comments using `--` are usually spaced clearly, even though `1        -- 1` can also be interpreted as `1 - -1`.  I think most databases support an alternative.

Comment: Could it be that it is already parse by somethng else? Then you need to change that and not the simple comment. Can you maybe show the parsing for the whole line?

Comment: I guess it's parsed completely as a regular sting. Maybe I should play with the string definition. This doesn't sound very safe but can work.

Comment: In that case, other lexer rules are conflicting with your `SIMPLE_COMMENT` rule. It is impossible to suggest without seeing your entire grammar.